# Creating anonymous objects in Python

Tags: python, oop

Is there any way I can create an anonymous object in Python? In Java I would write `new ClassName()`, but in Python it does not work

Comment: Just calling ClassName() creates an instance, and then you can store these in an array or something. Is that what you want?

Comment: What do you mean by "anonymous objects"? Are you asking how to create an object from a class in Python?

Comment: @AlexvanVliet I don't think this question is actually about anonymous classes...

Comment: @SH7890 That is exactly what I want, but I had problems after creating new objects in that way (without word `new`) in C++, will it work properly here?

Comment: Python != C++, and `new` isn't even a keyword...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yeah I thought so but after looking it isn't you're right. I didn't really understand the point of anonymous objects so I thought of anonymous classes, because an "anonymous object" is just an object not linked to a variable

Comment: @hooman You can do it that way in python. There is no new operator in python. You can use a list comprehension http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python if you want.